# How to import .so files from a packaged kivy android apk?

Tags: python, kivy, cython, buildozer

I'm trying to import .so files in python kivy, which works successfully when ran in Ubuntu but when I package to an apk and try to run it in Android phone, it loads the presplash then exits the app.

Below is the code on `test.py`

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ButtonApp(App): 
    def build(self):
    btn = Button(text ="hello world") 
    return btn 
def runM():
    root = ButtonApp()
    root.run()
```

So I converted the above file(`test.py`) to `test.so` file using `cython` then made a `main.py` file which calls the `runM` function

Below is `main.py`

```py
import test
test.runM()
```

Problem comes after packaging to apk, before that, everything is working just fine. In my `buildozer.spec`, `source.include_exts` I included so extension.

What I'm I missing?

Would appreciate assistance.

Comment: I don't understand the question - why do you think this has something to do with specifically importing shared object files? Have you debugged using adb logcat to get the actual error?

Comment: @inclement - because when I package importing .py file, apk runs just fine. How is it done though?

Comment: How is what done?

Comment: You need to [debug your application](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Not sure why you want to try importing shared libraries, but a shared library built for your Ubuntu machine will likely not work at all on an Android phone.

Comment: So, is there a way to build shared libraries for Android ?

Comment: @John Anderson .

Comment: Are you 100% sure you need to import a shared library? That is absolutely the wrong way to build an apk from your posted code.

Comment: How should I do it then ?

Comment: Have a look at [Buildozer](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html#buildozer). Note that there is no mention of creating shared libraries from your python code.